# Where to place code to set Firebase auth state persistence in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication

### Overview

I'm building a web app in Quasar/Vue.js and Firebase which needs to authenticate users.

### What I'm trying to achieve

A pretty common feature - keep users logged even after they close the browser/tab.

### Possible Solutions

I'm aware that I can use **localStorage** or **cookies** to set the user auth state. However, I want to allow Firebase auth do it for me (if it can do it).

I checked the docs in this regard - https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence
and they're nice, except I cannot figure out where to place this piece of code mentioned there:

```
firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL)
  .then(function() {
    // New sign-in will be persisted with session persistence.
    return firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
  });
```

I'm not sure where to place it out of the following places:

- with the `onAuthStatechanged` listener?
- in the App.vue (root Vue) instance?
- somewhere else?

Would be glad if anyone could help out. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd do it wherever you have `firebase.initializeApp()`. Eg

```js
firebase.initializeApp({
  // config goes here
});

export const auth = firebase.auth()

auth.setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL)
```

Note that `LOCAL` is the default in web apps already.

You don't really need to wait for that promise. From the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#setpersistence)

> This will return a promise that will resolve once the state finishes copying from one type of storage to the other. **Calling a sign-in method after changing persistence will wait for that persistence change to complete** before applying it on the new Auth state.

---

The modular version (v9+) of this would look like the following...

```js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import {
  browserLocalPersistence,
  getAuth, 
  setPersistence
} from "firebase/auth";

const app = initializeApp({
  // config goes here
})

export const auth = getAuth(app);

setPersistence(auth, browserLocalPersistence)
```

Comment: firebase.auth seems to not be there anymore in version 9 of firebase

Comment: @kamatheuska I've updated the answer to match v9 but it really shouldn't have been too difficult to migrate. The docs even show side-by-side comparisons of the namespaced vs module API

Comment: It is not about what is difficult but providing the most accurate answer for the user, don't you think?

Comment: @kamatheuska version-specific code in answers on StackOverflow is bound to go out-of-date eventually. Product documentation should always be the canonical source of truth

Comment: Not sure what your argument is or the purpose of it. Should we leave deprecated answers as they are? IMO what you did is the appropriate thing, edit the answer to reflect the current solution for the problem at hand.