# How to develop a presence detection function in firebase/vue.js

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication

I'm running an ERP App on vue.js/Firebase. My problem is:

I need to logout the user when the browser was closed. I found the `setPersistence()` function in this [firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence).

So, i tried to write this on main.js but it doesn't worked as i wanted (don't return any error log but don't logout when the browser is closed as well).

Here's my main.js code sample:

```js
import FirebaseVue  from './firebase/index'
import 'firebase/auth'
import Vue                  from 'vue'
import App                  from './App.vue'
import router               from './router'
import money                from 'v-money'
import Vuelidate            from 'vuelidate'
import { BootstrapVue, IconsPlugin,LayoutPlugin,ModalPlugin,CardPlugin,VBScrollspyPlugin,DropdownPlugin, TablePlugin}   from 'bootstrap-vue'
import { library }                                      from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { FontAwesomeIcon }                      from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'
import { VueMaskDirective }                     from 'v-mask'
import { 
    faTimesCircle,
    faPlusCircle,
    faCoffee,
    faHome,
    faLogout,
    faSignOutAlt,
    faEdit,
    faUpload,
    faDollarSign,
    faTimes,
    faClock,
    faCheck,
    faChevronLeft,
    faChevronRight,
    faArrowCircleLeft,
    faArrowCircleRight,
} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import firebase from 'firebase'

library.add(faTimesCircle,faPlusCircle,faCoffee,faHome,faSignOutAlt,faEdit,faUpload,faDollarSign,faTimes,faClock,faCheck,faChevronLeft,faChevronRight,faArrowCircleLeft,faArrowCircleRight)

Vue.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon)
Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
Vue.use(IconsPlugin)
Vue.use(LayoutPlugin)
Vue.use(ModalPlugin)
Vue.use(CardPlugin)
Vue.use(VBScrollspyPlugin)
Vue.use(DropdownPlugin)
Vue.use(TablePlugin)
Vue.use(FirebaseVue)
Vue.use(require('vue-moment'));
Vue.use(money, {precision: 4})
Vue.use(Vuelidate)

new Vue({
  router,
  render: h=>h(App),
  created(){
        
        this.$firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged( user => {
        let id_cliente = localStorage.getItem('id_client');
        let firebase     = this.$firebase.firestore();
            if (user) {
            
            firebase.collection('user_session')
            .doc(id_client).update({status:true})
            .then(
                console.log('sucess')
            ).catch((e)=>{
                console.log(e);
                console.log('doen't have a session log')
            });

            } else {
                
                firebase.collection('user_session')
                .doc(id_client).update({status:false})
                .then(
                    console.log('logout sucessfully')
                ).catch((e)=>{
                console.log(e);
                console.log('doens't have a log session')
            });

            }        
         }),

         firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.NONE).then( () => {
            console.log('sucess setpersistence')
        }).catch( error => {
            console.log('there's an error on persistence: ' + error)
        })

  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

How do i run this function? Am i missing something?

Comment: @JustinLevine Ok, i changed the persistence, but it also don't logout. According to the onAuthStateChanged() it have to change the state to _false_ in the firestore when i close the web page.

Comment: You are provided a second argument to "firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged" which should be an error handler.  You might try running: "this.$firebase.auth().setPersistence" outside of the "onAuthStateChanged" call.

Comment: I'm changed setPersistence as you told (changing the firebase to this.$firebase)
But it still don't logout the user. May i have to wrote something inside the sucess promisse response?

Comment: Yeah, disregard the error handler thing.  I was thrown off by the comma you have after the "onAuthStateChanged" call.  Not sure why its there.  Anyhow, there is a potential difference in instance between "firebase.auth()" and "this.$firebase.auth()".  I'm not sure if those will reference the same thing or not.

Comment: Yes, definitely you should wait for the success of the persistence to be set before logging in and doing other auth stuff.  The example in the docs logs in only after the Promise has resolved.

Comment: The comma is to tell the vue that is another function running on created(), whitout this comma the vue application crashes. i tried to write "onAuthStateChanged()" in the promisse response but it doesn't work as i wanted too; maybe i'm writing setPersistence on the wrong place?

Comment: If that's the case, it sounds like there's something off in your code.  There shouldn't be any issues of having to insert a comma to run multiple methods within the created() lifecycle hook.

Comment: Maybe i have to put this code on login method? as you told before?

Comment: Not sure.  I'd have to see the full code really.  I mean for sure the code above as it is wouldn't even run properly (console.log('doens't have a log session'))  And there seems to be some other code that is implemented to actually create the firebase session.

Comment: Understood, i would like to show you the entire code but the repository is set to private. there's some examples who don't use the callback (.then() response) like this question opened here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62078982/where-to-place-code-to-set-firebase-auth-state-persistence-in-vue-js

Answer (score 0):

setPresence() don't work fine to me, so i found a new way to detect when the user closes the web page and run a signout function:

Here's the docs:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence

On my app, i have a firebase.js file exported to main.js, here's my solution in firebase.js file:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/auth'
import 'firebase/storage'
import 'firebase/firestore'

export const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey:             xxx ,
  authDomain:         xxx ,
  databaseURL:        xxx ,
  projectId:          xxx ,
  storageBucket:      xxx ,
  messagingSenderId:  xxx ,
  appId:              xxx      
})

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged( user => {
  var uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
  var userStatusDatabaseRef = firebase.database().ref('/status/' + uid);

  var isOfflineForDatabase = {
    estado: 'offline',
    timestamp: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
  }
  
  var isOnlineForDatabase = {
    estado: 'online',
    timestamp: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
  }

  firebase.database().ref('.info/connected').on('value', function(snapshot){
    if(snapshot.val() == false){
      return;
    }
    userStatusDatabaseRef.onDisconnect().set(isOfflineForDatabase).then(function() {
      userStatusDatabaseRef.set(isOnlineForDatabase);
  });
  })
})

export default function install (Vue) {
  Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, '$firebase', {
    get(){
      return firebaseApp
    }
  })
}
```