# Firebase + Vue: Disconnected at refresh despite setting persistence

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication

I am using Vue and firebase to build an authentication mechanism. Every time I refresh the page, the authentication is dropped, and I am redirected to the login page.

I tried `setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION)` as per the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence). I also implemented a few of the tips of this [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/vuejs/comments/8q7xpz/firebase_auth_logs_in_but_redirects_to_login_at/). I am still being redirected, and I noticed that on refresh, the `auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {})` callback has `user = null`.

I am a bit stuck. Apologies if this is a newbie question.

**firebase.js**

```js
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/auth'
import 'firebase/firestore'

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.VUE_APP_API_KEY,
  ...
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

// utils
const db = firebase.firestore()
const auth = firebase.auth()
auth.setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION)


// export utils/refs
export {
  db,
  auth
}
```

**main.js**

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify';
import router from './router/index'
import { store } from './store'
import { auth } from './firebase'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

let app

auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (!app) {
    app = new Vue({
      router,
      store,
      vuetify,
      render: h => h(App)
    }).$mount('#app')
  }
  if (user) {
    store.dispatch('fetchUserProfile', user)
    store.commit('setEmail', user.email)
  }
  })
```

**router/index.js**

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';
import Login from '../components/Login'
import Dashboard from '../components/Dashboard'
import { auth } from '../firebase'

Vue.use(Router)

const router = new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes: [
      {
          path: '/login',
          name: 'login',
          component: Login,
          meta: {
            disableNavBar: true
          }
      },
      // ... other routes removed for brevity
      {
          path: '/dashboard',
          name: 'Dashboard',
          component: Dashboard,
          meta: {
            requiresAuth: true
        }
      },
    ]
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const requiresAuth = to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)
  if(to["path"] !== from["path"]){
    if(requiresAuth){
      auth.onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if (user) {
          console.log("Logged in", user) 
          next();
        } else {
          console.log("Here", user) //this logs user = null on refresh 
          next('/login')
        }
      });
    } else {
      next();
    }
  }
})

export default router
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel very stupid now, sharing this here as it might come handy to people facing this issue.

1. It turns out that I had a `logout` function in one of my unused `components.vue`. Even though it was never used by my application, it was initialized by vue. Each time that happened (meaning, on refresh), the component would be initialized, the script would be executed, and a `store.dispatch("logout")` would be ran. That caused a lot of useless redirections, on top of the user session being set to null.

I randomly stumbled upon that leftover code by searching for "logout" in my codebase out of despair about the issue. "Damn something must be logging me out". That something was just my own neglect.

2. That being fixed, setting `firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION)` works fine.

To those that took the time to answer this question, thank you and sorry :). In case someone stumbles upon this question, and had the same root cause, glad this helped.

Comment: I picked up a legacy codebase and found the problem because of your suggestion; just had to search all instances of `signOut`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `SESSION` as the auth persistence mode, you need to use `LOCAL` to make sure the session persists even after closing/refreshing the browser tab or window.

So, next to your `firebase.initializeApp()`, you could add this -

```js
firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL)
```

Comment: Thanks. I did try that as well. It does not work: I am still being logged out on refresh. + per the docs, SESSION should do the job. So I am assuming it has to do with something else.

Comment: Hmm, strange. I faced the exact problem some time ago. It worked with the LOCAL thing. I'll have a look again to see if something else comes up. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62079096/9978232